# La Sardina - blank film

Tags: film, lomo

I have recently bought La Sardina lomography camera and after shooting the film came out blank with some colour stains on it. The film was loaded and rewinded correctly and I don’t really know what to do.

[image]

Comment: Lomography is known for light leaks...  There might be a giant light "leak" in the film take-up compartment?

Comment: What’s the rest of the film look like?

Comment: That camera has a **fixed aperture of F8 and a fixed shutter speed of to 1/100th of a second** ( plus bulb for unlimited time exposures )  **And no light meter**.  So your lighting need to fall within the range acceptable for  F8 at to 1/100th for the ASA of the film you are using,  **or adjust your development times** to compensate for more or less than proper light conditions. *You will need a light meter or a long history of judging lighting conditions for a given ASA of film*.

Comment: Please tell us how you shot the film and in what conditions, how you handled the film before, during and after you loaded into the camera. What film, what ASA?

Answer (score 5):

You film has been exposed to light from a source that did not reach the film via the camera's shutter. The darkened edges of the film would not be exposed by taking an image using the camera. Even if your exposure settings completely overexposed the film using the camera's shutter, the edges of the film would not receive any of that light as it is masked by the film gate directly behind the shutter mechanism.

[image]

Comment: Agreed.  There are edge markings, so the film was (more or less) correctly processed.  The camera is massively malfunctioning.  It does not look like the shutter is working correctly, and it also looks like the camera has significant light leaks.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie In the example in the OP, the film is lacking edge markings in the areas that were totally exposed. This may not have happened in the camera at all. It may have happened in the handling of the film outside the camera.

Comment: It could have happened outside the camera, but given that it's a Lomo, it was more likely in the camera.  Still, I can't be sure. The edge markings would be gone in the fogged area no matter how the fogging happened.